# Plot - quarters in axis?

Tags: plot

I am new to TEX

How can I plot this variable and keep the quarters in the x axis ?

```
date    variable
1993Q1  0.71957432
1993Q2  0.622643199
1993Q3  0.557352546
1993Q4  0.78844216
1994Q1  0.677342246
1994Q2  0.752843835
1994Q3  0.823435891
1994Q4  0.869172377
1995Q1  0.822971248
1995Q2  0.759768686
1995Q3  0.662193784
1995Q4  0.744474674
1996Q1  0.665910923
1996Q2  0.776898876
1996Q3  0.923927404
1996Q4  0.840678042
1997Q1  0.735450535
1997Q2  0.850306776
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by `ybar` plot or `sharp` plot which uses `\pgfplotstableread` to read the datum into a table then plot the table

[image]

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}%[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date, variable
1993Q1, 0.71957432 
1993Q2, 0.622643199
1993Q3, 0.557352546 
1993Q4, 0.78844216 
1994Q1, 0.677342246 
1994Q2, 0.752843835 
1994Q3, 0.823435891 
1994Q4, 0.869172377 
1995Q1, 0.822971248 
1995Q2, 0.759768686 
1995Q3, 0.662193784 
1995Q4, 0.744474674 
1996Q1, 0.665910923 
1996Q2, 0.776898876 
1996Q3, 0.923927404 
1996Q4, 0.840678042 
1997Q1, 0.735450535 
1997Q2, 0.850306776
}\datatable

% ybar plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar, 
    height=10cm,
    width=13cm,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{date},
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east}
]
\addplot [fill=blue] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=variable] {\datatable};  

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

% -- sharp plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,
    width=13cm,
    enlarge y limits=false,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\datatable}{date},
    x tick label style={rotate=90, anchor=east}
]
%\addplot [fill=blue] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=variable] {\datatable};  
\addplot [sharp plot] table [x expr=\coordindex, y=variable] {\datatable};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that was very-very helpful. Can I make only specific quarters appear in the x axis , like only 1993q1,1994Q1,1995Q1 etc ?

Comment: You can use `skip coords between index={1}{5}` to skip data from 1 to 5. Be aware that the index starts from 0. For more infor please see section 4.21 on page 212 of the pgfplots manual.

Comment: Hi I mis-understood your question. You want to skip the xlabel, not the data. One way around is to leave the date entries blank.